# Android. Нижняя сенсорная панель кнопок

Tags: android, functional-buttons

Как программно определить высоту нижней панели с сенсорными кнопками (см. рисунок)

Дело в том, что панель на эмуляторе перекрывает мою вью. Нашел как программно определить наличие данной панели, но с программным определением ее высоты проблемы :)

```
    if(!ViewConfiguration.get((Context)this).hasPermanentMenuKey()) {
        // панель присутствует
    } else {
        // панель отсутствует
    }
```

Как называется данная панель? Как определить ее высоту?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Корневой лэйаут у вас должен иметь высоту `match_parent` и это решит вашу проблему простым и очвидным образом

Comment: Родитель вью и все роители родителей имеют высоту match_parent

Answer (score 2):

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
       Point size = new Point();
       display.getRealSize(size);
       Log.d("full size", size.x  + " x " + size.y);
   } else {
       int x = displayM.widthPixels;
       int y = displayM.heightPixels;
       Log.d("full size", x  + " x " + y);
   }

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
       Point size = new Point();
       display.getSize(size);
       Log.d("app size", size.x  + " x " + size.y);
   }
```

До 13 API телефоны не имеют подобных кнопок, дальше можете найти разницу между полным размером и размером приложения. Но может просто воспользоваться получением размера приложения?

Comment: Мне кажется есть более тривиальное решение (наподобия получения высоты статусбара). в любом случае спасибо за костыль ))

Comment: @RomanNovoselov а зачем вам знать размер кнопок? Может вообще какого-нибудь wrap_content / margin_bot хватит?

Comment: Кстати приложение ложится ПОД данную панель, так что полный размер и размер приложения будут равны получается

Comment: нужна высота данной панели, чтобы как раз сделать marginBottom

Answer (score 2):

Данная панель называется navigation bar. Её высота 48dp.